# How to access ServerVariables in AspnetCore 1.0

Tags: asp.net-core, httpcontext, server-variables, request.servervariables

In exisiting .Net Web Site, Server Variables is accessed using

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]
```

How to access the ServerVariables in AspnetCore 1.0 Web Application?
While debugging inside controller, `this.HttpContext.Features` does not contain `IServerVariablesFeature` .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, I am not going to directly answer your question. I am going to try and throw some light on why this server variable is not a problem anymore.

"HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE" is a server variable that IIS & .NET used to facilitate on ASP.NET framework to communicate content language with the application.

Back in the days, browsers weren't consistent and did not pass `Accept-Language` headers consistently.
To fill that gap, application servers such as IIS had to make it up by intelligently setting this up, by using the combination of headers, user agent string and default configuration on the server to make up something that is relevant for the application.

There are few reasons we don't want it anymore,

1. Almost all browsers set `Accept-Language` header. You can see this by simply going to Network tab in devtools of your favorite browser and inspecting HTTP request headers.

[image: Chrome browser showing accept language]

2. Http Request Message class in newer versions of .NET are very sane and clear to read.

   [Request Message in windows .NET framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage(v=vs.110).aspx)

   [HttpRequest class in dotnet core](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/HttpRequest.cs#L78)
3. It may simplify be easy to serve content based on the header in the request compared to some complex opaque logic written in the web server. After all the applications are getting lighter and so are the servers, it pays to be light and transparent. Why would somebody wants to write a complex logic in the webserver which it is not about really being a web server.

So, applications can simply inspect the Request Header collection.

Expanding on it a little more,
With dotnet core, there are number of features that are exposed, which the implementing of the web server can support. Details can be found [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/request-features.html?highlight=request).

More details that will help understand how the framework and webservers are neatly decoupled can be [found here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can't because the app now runs out of process. However, as humblelistener pointed out most of this information is available in other places. Was Accept Language the only one you needed?

Comment: these values are required 
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, REMOTE_ADDR

Comment: HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE is the Accept-Language header, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR is the X-Fowarded-For header (which you can use the ForwardedHeaders middleware to apply for you), and REMOTE_ADDR is HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress

Comment: Do you know what field is CERT_SUBJECT and what it is mapped to?

Comment: HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate.Subject

Comment: @humblelistener - While this is helpful for some items, the headers do not contain the REMOTE_USER value which was previously available in ServerVariables()

Comment: What about HttpContext.User?