# Retrieve ServerVariables in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net

I've implemented IdentityServer4. The application is running ASP.NET Core. The hosting environment is on IIS. I'm using Shibboleth to perform pre-authentication to the site. This populates a number of server variables in IIS. 
(We **cannot** use HTTP Headers in our environment, everything must be done using ServerVariables)

I want to retrieve either server variable 'AUTH_USER' or 'REMOTE_USER'.

In legacy ASP or ASP.NET this was as simple as calling Request.ServerVariable("AUTH_USER"). This has changed in ASP.NET Core.

I've tried 
ClaimsPricipal -> User.Identity.Name, (User name is empty, IsAuthenticated is false)

I've confirmed the server variables are in fact set.

[This question is similar to this question but doesn't answer the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38429604/how-to-access-servervariables-in-aspnetcore-1-0)

Comment: May be you have to use forwarded headers with middleware https://stackoverflow.com/q/51394593/10634638

Comment: We're not using headers. There are no headers to speak of, just 30 or so ServerVariables.

Answer (score 8):

In Asp.Net Core 3, there is an extension method `GetServerVariable` on the `HttpContext`.

To use it you need to install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions` NuGet package, and the actual method is in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContextServerVariableExtensions` class.

Note that the server has to support it, otherwise it will return `null`.

For earlier versions of ASP.Net Core you might be able to use the features property of the context property, by calling `context.Features.Get<IServerVariablesFeature>()`

Answer (score 4):

The .NET (Core) team changed this quite a few times in the last releases. I couldn't neither get HttpContextServerVariableExtensions version nor the legacy variant to via context features to work.

But [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jjxtra/3b240b31a1ed3ad783a7dcdb6df12c36) helped me. Works with .NET 5 on AWS fargate likely with some kind of load balancer pass-through.

```
public static class HttpContextExtensions
{
    //https://gist.github.com/jjxtra/3b240b31a1ed3ad783a7dcdb6df12c36

    public static IPAddress GetRemoteIPAddress(this HttpContext context, bool allowForwarded = true)
    {
        if (allowForwarded)
        {
            string header = (context.Request.Headers["CF-Connecting-IP"].FirstOrDefault() ?? context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].FirstOrDefault());
            if (IPAddress.TryParse(header, out IPAddress ip))
            {
                return ip;
            }
        }
        return context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
    }
}
```

I assume you can get any values like this out of the header. `HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"]`. Note that you cannot locally debug the headers. I didn't see those entries because of my local setup that differs. I saw what magic strings are available e.g. [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/get-client-ip-address-in-mvc-30).

Answer (score 0):

I am using .Net 7 and I had to use the request headers to get to the server variables.

```
HttpContext.Request?.Headers
```