# What is the .net core version of HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]

Tags: .net-core, httpcontext, http-host

I am trying to rewrite this line of code `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]`  it cant find current  it doesn't contain a definition.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63460106/1273882

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension in .net core. To use it you need to install prerequested package which denoted below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontextservervariableextensions.getservervariable?view=aspnetcore-5.0